Изменение переменных в скрипте меняет переменные в ScriptableObject
Создаю игру на Unity. Храню стартовые характеристики персонажей в ScriptableObject. В начале игровой сессии я присваиваю значения SO локальным переменным скрита. Однако при изменении этих локальных переменных почему то меняются и исходные значения в SO, хотя напрямую я их не трогаю.
public interface ICharacterValues
{
    public float speed { get; set; }
    public float speedMultiplier { get; set; } 
    StartValuesSet();       
}

public class CharacterSO : ScriptableObject
{
    public float speed;
    public float speedMultiplier;
}

public class CharacterValues : MonoBehaviour, ICharacterValues
{
    [SerializeField] private CharacterSO _characterSO;
    public float speed { get; set; }
    public float speedMultiplier { get; set; }

    private void OnEnable()
    {
        StartValuesSet();
    }

    public void StartValuesSet()
    {
        speed = _characterSO.speed;
        speedMultiplier = _characterSO.speedMultiplier;
    }

    public void SpeedUpgade()
    {
        speed *= speedMultiplier ;
    }
}

При этом, после изменения параметра speed из скрипта меняется и также и speed из SO из-за чего после выхода из плеймода значения там уже не те что нужны

У вас в названии класса СharacterValues русская буква С. Поправьте, чтобы не удивляться в будущем.

Залогайте (Debug.Log), когда у вас и как часто OnEnable отрабатывает. Магии не бывает.

Косяк с C только в вопросе. В коде с этим всё ок.

Проблема не в том, что speed получает неверное значение, а в том, что при этом меняется _characterSO.speed, которое я напрямую никак не меняю

я проверял дебагом и значение в SO менялось ровно в тот момент, когда я присваивал новое значение локальной переменной, т.е. в описанном примере сразу после строки speed *= speedMultiplier

В любом случае, проблема не в показанном коде, а за его пределами.

Если значения меняются, значит где-то есть операция присвоения, но не в том коде, что ты тут написал. Её можно легко найти, посмотрев ссылки на соответствующее поле.
Но причина ошибки в первую очередь из-за нарушения инкапсуляции! Вот как выглядит код, дающий гарантии, где присвоения нет и быть не может, исключительно модель данных для чтения:
public class UnitProfile : ScriptableObject
{
    [SerializeField] private string _name;
    [SerializeField] private float[] _baseStats;

    public string Name => _name;
    public IEnumerable<float> BaseStats => _baseStats;
}

Очень хорошей идеей является использовать ScriptableObject для профилей юнитов, где в частности указаны базовые статы. Но как-то странно плодить SO для каждого значения, работать с этим, это какой-то суровый челендж.
IСharacterValues это абстракция, но почему-то в нём поля с вполне конкретным именем. Модификаторы public там кстати не нужны, интерфейс сам по себе контракт для внешнего пользователя, поэтому там и так всё public. И не очень понятно для чего этот интерфейс тут нужен... словно есть некие Сharacter, но без неких Values и отличить одних от других, можно с помощью этого интерфейса.
Тебе стоит посмотреть варианты, как люди реализовывают StatSystem, например этот вариант.

Увы ссылки я может уже не посмотрю, так как уже заменил SO просто отдельным классом, но на сколько я помню всё таки никаких присвоений значений я для него не делал. И да, мой SO изначально выглядел как его реализовали вы и должен был хранить как раз таки базовые статы, но описанная проблема была уже тогда. Абстракция же нужна т.к. у меня есть несколько наследуемых классов с одинаковыми переменными но разной реализацией методов (я уже перешёл от интерфейса до абстрактного класса). А за пример реализации системы статов спасибо, я посмотрю.

АААааа... у тебя типа отдельные классы для Player, Enemy... и по этому ICharacterValues. Но тогда интерфейс должен называться что-то типа IStatsOwner, что бы отражать то, чем является абстракция. Но вообще это профанство делать всё разными классами, нужно стремиться к единому.

Система в статье по ссылке не идеальна и не полноценна, это сам по себе пример, один из возможных, да и ту можно допиливать и допиливать до приличного юзабилити, типами модификаторов, редакторами, интерфейсами и т.д.
